# Online resources dyscalculia

Tags: references

I'm an adult with dyscalculia who is currently in a position that requires me to at least try to learn basic statistical concepts. Unfortunately there is more information out there about people like me than there is for people like me.

My university is constantly asking me what I need to not be this bad at numbers even though I myself ofcourse have no clue and I'm a little at my wits end.

That's why I'm looking for online resources that break down statistical concepts in ridiculously, almost embarrassingly small pieces. Basically like they're being explained to someone who's never seen a number before.

All the resources I've found so far are aimed at children and not of very much assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are visual analogies fine? Most statistical concepts translate into the areas of various shapes, overlaps between areas and so on.

Comment: Yes, those are helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I always end up going back to one site: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/

I believe this website might help a lot, if you have not checked it out already.  Why do I feel that this website is good?  It's written in a very personal way, sort of like how a person would talk in real life.  It also has very nice visuals and formulas that are well laid out.  There are also tables, calculator help, and other items on this site that I tend to use when checking myself.

Comment: I've checked it out and I like how everything is truly explained in a step by step fashion. Thank you for your suggestion.